# MATLAB program takes more and more of my memory

Tags: matlab

I'm going to write a program in MATLAB that takes a function, sets the value D from 10 to 100 (the for loop), integrates the function with Simpson's rule (the while loop) and then displays it. Now, this works fine for the first 7-8 values, but then it takes longer time and eventually I run out of memory, and I don't understand the reason for this. This is the code so far:

```
global D;
s=200;  
tolerance = 9*10^(-5);  
for D=10:1:100  
    r = Simpson(@f,0,D,s);  
    error = 1;  
    while(error>tolerance)  
        s = 2*s;  
        error = (1/15)*(Simpson(@f,0,D,s)-r);  
        r = Simpson(@f,0,D,s);  
    end  
    clear error;  
    disp(r)  
end
```

Comment: Nothing in your code looks bad.  Can you post `f`?.  Is `Simpson` your own routine?  Looking at the Mathworks site, it looks like `quad` (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html) is the standard Simpson's rule function.  You might post that too.  And just in general style notes, does `D` need to be global; `clear error` is probably unnecessary, and do you need to reinitialize `s` before the `while` loop?

Answer (score 2):

[mtrw's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120261/mtrw) comment probably already answers the question in part: `s` should be reinitialized inside the for loop. The posted code results in `s` increasing irreversibly every time the error was too large, so for larger values of `D` the *largest* `s` *so far* will be used.

Additionally, since the code re-evaluates the entire integration instead of reusing the previous integration from [0, D-1] you waste lots of resources unless you want to explicitly show the error tolerance of your `Simpson` function - `s` will have to increase a lot for large `D` to maintain the same low error (since you integrate over a larger range you have to sum up more points).

Finally, your implementation of `Simpson` could of course do funny stuff as well, which no one can tell without seeing it...